# Clean up MySQL privileges

Tags: mysql, access-control-list, permissions

Is it possible to delete users/privileges who exist but don't have access to a database (excluding users with global privileges)

Also I notice a number of "database-specific privileges" that no longer exist are still assigned to the user even after delete the database?

Comment: You can use the data in mysql.* and information_schema.* to find/delete users. But be very careful doing so - there's lots of non-user-related data in there and deleting the wrong record(s) can kill your database. Try mysql.users and information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGES as a starting point.

Comment: I have thousand, I thought there might be some clean up script that can automatically delete these.

Comment: No. but it shouldn't be too hard to have a query find all the "dangling" records and delete them. This is all due to the info_schem and mysql databases using MyISAM, so there's no referential integrity checks being done - not everyone has InnoDB enabled, so the internal system tables/databases have to be in an engine that's guaranteed to be available, which is myisam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table level privileges :

```
select * from mysql.tables_priv;
```

DB level privileges :

```
select * from mysql.db;
```

I am sure you know that you have to `flush privileges` every time you change permissions.

Try [this](http://www.grahamwideman.com/gw/tech/mysql/perms/index.htm) for more info on privileges.

Having said that, as far as my experience goes, you have to cleanup the user privileges as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

you should refer to [`drop user`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/drop-user.html)

```
select * from mysql.user;
```

then with the drop user command it will delete privileges
and the entries in db (table) as well